# PHP Mysql Get Table Last Updated Time & Date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the last update time & date whenever MySQL tables were updated with the latest changes, I got the below PHP code working in PHP 5 but not the latest version PHP 7 and return an error showing nothing on the web page, trying to fix it but no avail, anyone got any idea what went wrong?

```
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("information_schema") or die(mysql_error());
     $query1 = "SELECT 'UPDATE_TIME' FROM 'TABLES' WHERE 'TABLE_SCHEMA' LIKE 'demo' AND 'TABLE_NAME' LIKE 'usc'";
     $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
       echo "<font color='red'>&nbsp; (Last update : ".$row['UPDATE_TIME'].")</font>";
```

Comment: Hello. Firstly, in your code, you can see that it is vulnerable to SQL Injection [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Its important to use Prepared statements to avoid SQL Injections. So, in this code **TABLE_SCHEMA** and **TABLE_NAME** are columns from **TABLES**? In general, you would like to update **UPDATE_TIME** every time that this table **TABLES** were update?

Comment: thanks for ur input.  I got mysql tables name 'demo' and 'usc'; yes i wish to dispay latest time when tables were updated.

Comment: You can use this php class to convert your `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_` https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9199-PHP-Replace-mysql-functions-using-the-mysqli-extension.html

Comment: thank you sir, will have a look on your suggestion

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message

Answer (score 0):

the *mysql* family of functions is removed in PHP 7 As far as I know. You may only use *mysqli* and *pdo*. I recommend switching to PDO, as it has more flexibility. See the [mysql requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.requirements.php). Assuming that you have transitioned to PDO, you can use the following code to achieve the same thing:

```
//select the appropriate database
$pdo_object->query('use information_schema');
$query1 = "SELECT 'UPDATE_TIME' FROM 'TABLES' WHERE 'TABLE_SCHEMA' LIKE 'demo' AND 'TABLE_NAME' LIKE 'usc'";
$query1 = $pdo_object->prepare($query1);
$query1->execute();
while($row = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<font color='red'>&nbsp; (Last update : ".$row['UPDATE_TIME'].")</font>";
}
```

The aforementioned code also mitigates the MySQL Injection vulnerabilities that your code may be exposed to.

Comment: thank you sir, let me explore further with your input, it's useful.

Comment: My pleasure, if you need help setting up PDO or anything else, feel free to comment.

Comment: hi do i need to include mysql_connect in the first line?

Comment: as I previously mentioned, mysql is removed in PHP 7, you will need to setup PDO. More info on setting this up can be found [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).